# Classification of the normal subgroups of the discrete Heisenberg group

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, heisenberg-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $H$ be the discrete Heisenberg group, i.e., the set of matrices of the form

$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & x & z \\
0 & 1 & y \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

where $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then what are all of the normal subgroups of $H$? Is there a nice classification of them?

We know that in this case $H$ is 2-step nilpotent, and in fact $Z(H)=[H,H] \cong \mathbb{Z}$. But are there any other normal subgroups? (which are not contained in the center)

Comment: Each normal subgroup has a Hirsch length $h\in\{0,1,2,3\}$. $h=0$: only the normal subgroup $\{1\}$. $h=1$: these are the finite index subgroups of the (cyclic) center. $h=2$: these are abelian subgroups, free abelian of rank 2; they contain a finite index subgroup of the center (up to commensuration, these are index by $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbf{Q}$, according to their infinite cyclic projection in $\mathbf{Z}^2$). $h=3$: these are normal finite index subgroups.

Comment: PS: if you describe quotients rather than normal subgroups, writing $h'=3-h$ (Hirsch length of the quotient), $h'=3$ corresponds to the whole quotient; $h'=2$ correspond to the Heisenberg group with 13-entry in $\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$ for some $n$ ($n=1$ is the quotient $\mathbf{Z}^2$, namely the abelianization). $h'=1$ corresponds to finite-by-cyclic quotients. $h'=0$ corresponds to finite quotients (e.g., Heisenberg over $\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$, abelian quotients, but these are not the only ones).

Comment: Every subgroup containing $Z(H)$ is a normal subgroup of $H$ since $[H,H] = Z(H)$.

Comment: It's pretty fortunate that Heisenberg group is free 2-step nilpotent on 2 generators; so there's a pretty nice description of quotients. That is, *all* 2-or-less-generated 2-or-less-step nilpotent groups.